# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

I am a newbie in spring. I have practiced spring core, it was all good until spring configuration came into picture without boot. i tried very hard to search the error in the internet but got no answer to my error.
please, help me get through this, I have given all my codes in this question description.
and tried MVC code in spring MVC and got the following error:

```
        HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception


        type Exception report

        message Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception

        description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

        exception
        javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


        root cause
        org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/telusko-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
            org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
            javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


        root cause
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver
            org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
            org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
            org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:251)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1389)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
            org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
            javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

In my console, error is :

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception


    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet telusko threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


    root cause
    org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/telusko-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


    root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:251)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1389)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:639)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

my controller HomeController.java :

```
    package com.telusko.springmvc;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import com.telusko.springmvc.model.Alien;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController
    {
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home()
        {
            return "index";
        }
        @RequestMapping("add")
        public String add(@RequestParam("num1")int i,@RequestParam("num2")int j,Model m)
        {
            int num3 = i+j;
            m.addAttribute("ans",num3);
            return "result";
        }
        @RequestMapping("addAlien")
        public String addAlien(@ModelAttribute ("alienObject") Alien a, Model m)
        {
                    
            m.addAttribute("Alien",a);
            
            return "result";
        }
        @ModelAttribute
        public void modelData(Model m)
        {
            m.addAttribute("name","Aliens");
        }
        
    }
```

my JSP pages : index.jsp -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>STS Spring boot practise</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="IndianRed">
    Welcome to Shubham's World !!!

    <form action="addAlien">
        Enter your id : <input type="text" name="aid"><br>
        Enter your name : <input type="text" name="aname"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  isELIgnored="false"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>STS Spring boot practise</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightcoral">
        <!-- Result is: ${Alien} -->
        Alien Set : ${alienObject}
    
    
        Welcome Back ${name}...!!!
    </body>
    </html>

web.xml :
```

````
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >


<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/telusko-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```
configuration xml file : telusko-servlet.xml :
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.telusko.springmvc"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourseViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```
my pom.xml file:
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
  <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.25.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

 
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>springmvc</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a typo in your spring config xml file it should be "InternalResourceViewResolver" you miss typed as "InternalResourseViewResolver"